# How do i check that the button1 will not move out of the pictureBox1 bounds/borders?

Tags: c#, winforms

This is the code in timer1 the button is moving randomaly around over the pictureBox1 but sometimes its moving out the bounds.

I tried to check first for the top bound/border of the pictureBox1 but its not working it keep leaving the pictureBox area sometimes.

This is the original code in the timer:

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (currentPosition.X != randomPoint.X)
            {
                if (currentPosition.X > randomPoint.X)
                    currentPosition.X -= 1;
                else
                    currentPosition.X += 1;

                button1.Location = currentPosition;
            }
            else if (currentPosition.Y != randomPoint.Y)
            {
                if (currentPosition.Y > randomPoint.Y)
                    currentPosition.Y -= 1;
                else
                    currentPosition.Y += 1;

                button1.Location = currentPosition;
            }
            else
            {
                randomPoint.X = r.Next(0, pictureBox1.Width - button1.Width - 1);
                randomPoint.Y = r.Next(0, pictureBox1.Height - button1.Height - 1);
            }
        }
```

And this is after i tried to add the checking for the pictureBox1 top:

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int maxScreenHeight = pictureBox1.Height - button1.Size.Height;
            int maxScreenWidth = pictureBox1.Width - button1.Size.Width;
            if (button1.Top < 0)
                button1.Top = 0;
            else if (button1.Top > maxScreenHeight)
                button1.Top = maxScreenHeight;
            else
            {
                if (currentPosition.X != randomPoint.X)
                {
                    if (currentPosition.X > randomPoint.X)
                        currentPosition.X -= 1;
                    else
                        currentPosition.X += 1;

                    button1.Location = currentPosition;
                }
                else if (currentPosition.Y != randomPoint.Y)
                {
                    if (currentPosition.Y > randomPoint.Y)
                        currentPosition.Y -= 1;
                    else
                        currentPosition.Y += 1;

                    button1.Location = currentPosition;
                }
                else
                {
                    randomPoint.X = r.Next(0, pictureBox1.Width - button1.Width - 1);
                    randomPoint.Y = r.Next(0, pictureBox1.Height - button1.Height - 1);
                }
            }
        }
```

But it's not working. How can i make the checkings for the top left right and bottom ? So the button will not move out of the bounds ?

Comment: Your button goes out of the picturebox because you didn't set the parent of button to be the picturebox.

Comment: Also forgot to mention my pictureBox1 in the designer is set to the BorderStyle Fixed3 if it's any matter.

Comment: valter i tried it now in the constructor i did: button1.Parent = pictureBox1.Parent; using in the timer1 my original code in my question it didn't work.

Comment: Nop. button1.Parent = pictureBox1;

Comment: When you set `button1.Parent = pictureBox1;` then you should set the location of the `button` relatively with the `picturebox`: `button1.Location = new Point(x, y)` where `x, y` are the coordinates from the location of `picturebox` **not** the `form`, eg x=0 and y=0 will place the button at the exact location of `picturebox`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

my first concern is, you are using too many if-elseif-else branches, without any need to. There is, IMO, a floor in the logics, many code parts may most of the time not be entered at all.

Moreover, what is maybe too pedantic, but you are wasting resources on always computing the upper bounds in your call for random number. It is, again just my oppinion, much nicer to precompute those values just once and keep them known, without all-the-time asking for their computation, no matter how little the processor has to do, make it easier for it.

Edit: yes, as mentioned by valter, you either could make pictureBox the parent of the button, or just set lower bound for the random number : that would be the LOWER_LIMITs

Then, I think this should be the code you are trying to come up with:

```
namespace stackoverflow.com/questions/22135510
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public int X_UPPER_LIMIT = 0;
        public int Y_UPPER_LIMIT = 0;

        public int X_LOWER_LIMIT = 0; 
        public int Y_LOWER_LIMIT = 0; 

        public Point randomPoint = new Point();
        public Point newPosition = new Point();

        public Random r = new Random();

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            //care here, remove the pitureBox1.Location effects, if pictureBox is parent to the button
            X_UPPER_LIMIT = pictureBox1.Location.X + pictureBox1.Width - button1.Width - 1
            Y_UPPER_LIMIT = pictureBox1.Location.Y + pictureBox1.Height - button1.Height - 1;

            X_LOWER_LIMIT = pictureBox1.Location.X + 1; //set this to 0, if pictureBox is parent of button
            Y_LOWER_LIMIT = pictureBox1.Location.Y + 1; //set this to 0, if pictureBox is parent of button
            timer1.Start();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //first, lets call the randoms at the start of tick
            randomPoint.X = r.Next(X_LOWER_LIMIT, X_UPPER_LIMIT);
            randomPoint.Y = r.Next(Y_LOWER_LIMIT, Y_UPPER_LIMIT);

            newPosition.X = button1.Location.X;
            newPosition.Y = button1.Location.Y;

            //now, lets update positions, if they are not equal
            if (button1.Location.X != randomPoint.X)
            {
                if (button1.Location.X > randomPoint.X)
                    newPosition.X--;
                else
                    newPosition.X++;
            }

            if (button1.Location.Y != randomPoint.Y)
            {
                if (button1.Location.Y > randomPoint.Y)
                    newPosition.Y--;
                else
                    newPosition.Y++;
            }

            button1.Location = newPosition;
        }
    }
}
```

*side note: I have eventually written and run this, works for me.*

Comment: jmodark im trying your code now the b utton1 is like dancing in the place on a very small area in the pictureBox. It's not moving and sliding from place to place. In my first code in my question the original one its moving like sliding around the pictureBox1 area . In your code it looks like its dancing/jumping on very small area in the pictureBox1 area. Dosent move long dosent slide.

Comment: In my code timer1 interval set to 10ms if its 1000ms the button is moving very slow.

Comment: Also forgot to mention my pictureBox1 in the designer is set to the BorderStyle Fixed3 if it's any matter.

Comment: Moving on small area is what I was intending to do. If you want it to be changing position, then change `newPosition.X--` parts to be either `newPosition.X = newPosition.X + 10` or some constant OR `newPosition.X = randomPoint.X`

Comment: If all other things are okay, then by changing these commands, you can adjust size of moves, you could even make it either some adjustable number (e.g. by attaching slidebar on your main form) OR making the movement size another random number, limited ofc.

Comment: Your upper limit should be `pictureBox1.Location.X + pictureBox1.Width - button1.Width - 1` and `pictureBox1.Location.Y + pictureBox1.Height - button1.Height - 1` in case button has the form as a parent. The lower limit dont need the `+1`.

Comment: @valter oh boy, spot on, so I should edit that. Considering Lower limit I do not like borders touching and colliding with each other. Apart from my preference, it does not need to be.

Comment: @valter - well considering it once more, it deeply depends on whether the button is bound to the pictureBox. Hence in my test app it is not bound, then it has to be in the way you just corrected me. If it is bound, then the original style is just about okay. Isn't it?

Comment: What do you mean `bound`? Parent or bound rectangle?

Comment: Parent. (meaning picturebox is parent to button)